# basic django site gives error as "Not found: /nettrack/

Tags: python, django

I am totally new to django and stuck with basic learning of django. I have below structure of django project:
G:\virtualenvs\Netsite\netmon-- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/forfm.png)

I have below urls.py under netmon
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOPdy.png)

I have below urls.py under nettrack

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvHGZ.png)

[This is basic_generic.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV6zI.png)

And I have below index.html
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hZOj.png)

Now, whats wrong? I get error as below in the cmd window of "python manage.py runserver"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOmUS.png)
Please help. Also, I dont know whether I need any IIS running on my windows desktop machine so as to test site as http:/127.0.0.1:8000/nettrack/ in edge browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have /netmon/nettrack in path in urls and /nettrack in html

It's better to use the name property.

```
<a href="{% url 'index' %}">
```

Comment: I have already tried that. It is not working. If I change main urls.py as below         urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('nettrack/', include("nettrack.urls")),
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='nettrack/', permanent=True)),         Then I get error as       Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
[24/Apr/2020 06:12:09] "GET /nettrack/ HTTP/1.1" 200 25

Comment: {% url 'index' %} uses name attribute, you dont have name in path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='nettrack/', permanent=True), name="hereName") and not sure but i don't know if url attribute in redirectview can be relative

Comment: I resolved the problem by a trick...i referred a page https://realpython.com/get-started-with-django-1/#...did exactly what is written and then replaced it with my code...the error was gone after a little effort, What I understood is ..the paths are very important. Now I am getting some error with my base_generic.html. Hope to resolve it soon, else may post it here